# Creating multiple entities in single request in Microsoft Dynamics CRM (OData)

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I know how to create a single entity in single request. However, one requirement wants me to create multiple entities (in my case it's multiple entries in `ContactSet`). I tried putting array to

`POST /XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet`

```
[{
    "MobilePhone": "+0012 555 555 555",
    "YomiFullName" : "Demo User 1",
    "GenderCode" : {
        "Value" : 1
      }
     .....
     <data removed for sanity>
     .....    
},
 {
    "MobilePhone": "+0012 555 555 111",
    "YomiFullName" : "Demo User 2",
    "GenderCode" : {
        "Value" : 1
      }
     .....
     <data removed for sanity>
     .....    

}]
```

However this does not work and I could not find any documentation explaining me ways to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On which version are you working? Do you need to create records in a single transaction?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I am working on Dynamics CRM 2016. Unfortunately I am limited to either WebApi or Organization Data Service (`XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc`) so want to achieve it through those options only. I want to know if there is a way to create multiple records in a single transaction? I am sort of importing contact from other system to CRM so need to write importer kinda utility.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an [ExecuteMultipleRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultiplerequest.aspx), I don't believe this is available in Rest service however, but is available in the SOAP service.

```
// Get a reference to the organization service.
using (_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serverConfig.OrganizationUri, serverConfig.HomeRealmUri,serverConfig.Credentials, serverConfig.DeviceCredentials))
{
    // Enable early-bound type support to add/update entity records required for this sample.
    _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

    #region Execute Multiple with Results
    // Create an ExecuteMultipleRequest object.
    requestWithResults = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
    {
        // Assign settings that define execution behavior: continue on error, return responses. 
        Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
        {
            ContinueOnError = false,
            ReturnResponses = true
        },
        // Create an empty organization request collection.
        Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
    };

    // Create several (local, in memory) entities in a collection. 
    EntityCollection input = GetCollectionOfEntitiesToCreate();

    // Add a CreateRequest for each entity to the request collection.
    foreach (var entity in input.Entities)
    {
        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest { Target = entity };
        requestWithResults.Requests.Add(createRequest);
    }

    // Execute all the requests in the request collection using a single web method call.
    ExecuteMultipleResponse responseWithResults =
        (ExecuteMultipleResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(requestWithResults);

    // Display the results returned in the responses.
    foreach (var responseItem in responseWithResults.Responses)
    {
        // A valid response.
        if (responseItem.Response != null)
            DisplayResponse(requestWithResults.Requests[responseItem.RequestIndex], responseItem.Response);

        // An error has occurred.
        else if (responseItem.Fault != null)
            DisplayFault(requestWithResults.Requests[responseItem.RequestIndex], 
                responseItem.RequestIndex, responseItem.Fault);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer James. Isn't this something similar to batch operations?

Comment: @RahulPatil, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I think the answer is yes.

Comment: It is good to add that the `ExecuteMultipleRequest` is of limited use. The requests it contains do not participate in a single transaction and are executed sequentially, so the only gain here is less round-trips to the server.

Answer (score 3):

ExecuteMultipleRequest is a good  but not the only way. If you use CRM 2016 you can use Batch operations that is available in new WebApi. Check article that describes it - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607719.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Web API action ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607600.aspx)) to execute an `ExecuteTransactionRequest`, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executetransactionrequest.aspx). Subject of the example on MSDN is the `WinOpportunityRequest`, but it should work with any supported request, including custom actions.